# How should I cite a paper on arxiv correctly?

Tags: citations, arxiv

I'm writing my thesis. For example, this paper on arxiv.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473

I'm using Overleaf. I used `Export Bibtex Citation` on arxiv and paste the information into the `.bib` file. The result is shown as in the graph.

But my prof says I should add the detailed information of the references such as pages, number, and volume.

I'm very confused, how should I do this? Are this information contained in the Bibtex Citation from arxiv?

[image]

The exported information is

```
@misc{https://doi.org/10.48550/arxiv.1409.0473,
  doi = {10.48550/ARXIV.1409.0473},
  
  url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473},
  
  author = {Bahdanau, Dzmitry and Cho, Kyunghyun and Bengio, Yoshua},
  
  keywords = {Computation and Language (cs.CL), Machine Learning (cs.LG), Neural and Evolutionary Computing (cs.NE), Machine Learning (stat.ML), FOS: Computer and information sciences, FOS: Computer and information sciences},
  
  title = {Neural Machine Translation by Jointly Learning to Align and Translate},
  
  publisher = {arXiv},
  
  year = {2014},
  
  copyright = {arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license}
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but the paper in your example has actually been published at a conference (see the comment field on arXiv), so unless you need to cite something specifically that's only present in the arXiv version, you should mention the conference as the venue.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thank you, I have updated question. But how should I modify my `.bib` file and cite it in my text to show the information? Is the information of the conference contained in the above exported bib information?

Comment: @user900476 you will probably either have to add the info manually or look at the conference/journal websites where the papers have been "officially" published if they provide exportable citations.

Comment: @Sursula Thank you! I see. I've found the more detailed bibtex citation source on https://dblp.org/rec/journals/corr/BahdanauCB14.html. So never use arxiv bibtex at first I guess?

Comment: @user900476 I believe ICLR (and for that matter arXiv) doesn't have the concept of page numbers and volumes. All you can include is venue name and year (and identifier if you cite from arXiv).

Comment: @user900476 There is nothing wrong with using arXiv bibtex, as long as you want to cite the arXiv version of a paper, and not the conference/journal version (if it exists).

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thank you! My prof might be a little bit stubborn and might not know the arxiv citation form. (He's not reseaching on AI)

Comment: @GoodDeeds btw the arxiv citation form still does not show the paper is from arxiv? i.e. when I use `\cite{https://doi.org/10.48550/arxiv.1409.0473}`, the result is shown as [1] in the graph. It does not show it is from arxiv? i.e. the link. Although the url information is contained in the exported bibtex citation form?

Comment: @user900476 That is probably because of the bibliography style you are using (probably `\bibliographystyle` in your latex file). You can find more information in the [documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_bibliography_styles) or on [tex.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I'm using `\bibliographystyle{plain}`

Comment: Talk to your professor politely and patiently, and explain that arXiv does not have volume and page numbers. If they still insist, then remove the arXiv reference from our bibliography list and use a footnote reference instead.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: You should include detailed information about the paper you cite, and you have not done this. This is why your prof is confused.

---

If the screenshot is how the citation looks in your thesis, then it's obvious why your advisor is confused.

You have shown only the authors' names, title, and year. Anybody reading your thesis will be confused how they are expected to search for the paper, and how they can be sure that they found the same paper that you meant.

This is why, when citing a journal article, you include not only authors' names, title and year, but also journal title, volume, number, and preferrably pages. This will give readers a very clear indication which work has been cited.

If you cite a paper from arXiv, you should include information that will explicitly say that this is an arXiv preprint, and give readers some obvious way to find the paper on arXiv. An arXiv url perfectly fits this purpose, or alternatively you can use any wording that will convey the same information, e.g. "digital preprint, arXiv #1409.0473", or something similar. Your prof should be able to tell which style is preferrable for your thesis.

Note that arXiv url is already present in your bibtex record, so it is just a matter of TeX or BibTeX configuration to have it shown in the citation. My TeXfu is rusty, but I remember tinkering a lot with configs to show the citations exactly as I see fit in my thesis some 10 years ago.

And regarding the comments by your prof, most probably they thought that this is a citation from a journal, and therefore asked to include the said information. Without anything indicating that this is an arXiv publication, it is quite natural to think that this is a journal citation. If you tell them that this is an arXiv paper, they most probably would not require journal name etc., but would require an arXiv url or similar information as I have explained above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your boss is not aware that your article is available in a standard way / in a journal?
From the link you provided I exported the citation the way GoogleScholar suggests it, I think in this way it becomes clear that this is an arXiv article.

```
@article{bahdanau2014neural,
   title={Neural machine translation by jointly learning to align and translate},
   author={Bahdanau, Dzmitry and Cho, Kyunghyun and Bengio, Yoshua},
   journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1409.0473},
   year={2014}
}
```

Keep in mind: What information is being displayed in your references of the compiled PDF in what style/format depends on your bibtex settings. I think in your file bibtex items of class "misc" are simply not displayed with all the information you want to see.